# login and registration demo code using flask, sqlalchemy and angular , json

Tags: json, angular, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask, sqlalchemy ,angular and json but I am buliding an application where I am using these technologies so anyone can provide me small login and registration page demo or share link with me.

Answer (score 0):

Thinkster has a example application written in a lot of frameworks. They also have it written in Angular and Flask. There is login/registration functionality included in the application.
[Github repository](https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/) they walk you through building a modern web application with Python, Flask, and Angular. With Angular, you will build a SPA (Single Page App) that allows users to browse through exams and questions. These users, when authenticated, will be able to test their knowledge regarding a specific topic by choosing one of the multiple choices that a question exposes. Then, when your users submit their answers, your backend will check if they are right or wrong, record the result, and send back this result to users.